# How to match between row values

Tags: python, pandas

| serial | name | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 5,6,8 |
| 2 | Steve | 1,7 |
| 3 | Kevin | 4 |
| 4 | Kevin | 3 |
| 5 | John | 1,6,8 |
| 6 | Johnn | 1,5,8 |
| 7 | Steves | 2 |
| 8 | John | 1,5,6 |

Need to check and match the name of each row with the name of the row serial number mentioned in it's match column. Keep the serials matching else remove it. If nothing is matching then put null.

| serial | name | match | updated_match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 5,6,8 | 5,8 |
| 2 | Steve | 1,7 |  |
| 3 | Kevin | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | Kevin | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | John | 1,6,8 | 1,8 |
| 6 | Johnn | 1,5,8 |  |
| 7 | Steves | 2 |  |
| 8 | John | 1,5,6 | 1,5 |

Comment: I see that you've included the "pandas" tag. Should we assume that you're using dataframes? What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: Could you clarify the algorithm please? For serial 1, `John` is the name associated with serial numbers `5,6,8`, so shouldn't the result be `5,6,8`? And why are there `Johnn` and `Steves` in the output? Are they just typos?

Comment: They are not typos, John in row 1 is matching with index 5 and 8 but not matching with 6th index. So the output for index 1 will be 5,8

Comment: Oh, so the input is supposed to have `Johnn` and `Steves`?

Answer (score 0):

Convert values of `serial` column to strings,then mapping aggregate `set`s to Series wth same size like original, split column `match` and get difference with intersection of sets, last sorting and join back to strings:

```
s = df['serial'].astype(str)
sets = df['name'].map(s.groupby(df['name']).agg(set))
match = df['match'].str.split(',')

df['updated_match'] = [','.join(sorted(b.difference([c]).intersection(a))) 
                        for a, b, c in zip(match, sets, s)]
print (df)
   serial    name  match updated_match
0       1    John  5,6,8           5,8
1       2   Steve    1,7              
2       3   Kevin      4             4
3       4   Kevin      3             3
4       5    John  1,6,8           1,8
5       6   Johnn  1,5,8              
6       7  Steves      2              
7       8    John  1,5,6           1,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mappings to determine which match have the same names:

```
# ensure we have strings in serial
df = df.astype({'serial': 'str'})

# split and explode he individual serials
s = df['match'].str.split(',').explode()
# make a mapper: serial -> name
mapper = df.set_index('serial')['name']
# get exploded names
s2 = df.loc[s.index, 'serial'].map(mapper)

# keep only match with matching names
# aggregate back as string
df['updated_match'] = (s[s.map(mapper).eq(s2)]
                       .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
                       .reindex(df.index, fill_value='')
                      )
```

output:

```
  serial    name  match updated_match
0      1    John  5,6,8           5,8
1      2   Steve    1,7              
2      3   Kevin      4             4
3      4   Kevin      3             3
4      5    John  1,6,8           1,8
5      6   Johnn  1,5,8              
6      7  Steves      2              
7      8    John  1,5,6           1,5
```

Alternative with a `groupby.apply`:

```
df['updated_match'] = (df.groupby('name', group_keys=False)
                         .apply(lambda g: g['match'].str.split(',').explode()
                                          .loc[lambda x: x.isin(g['serial'])]
                                          .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))
                         .reindex(df.index, fill_value='')
                      )
```